# Nginx + Gunicorn+Flask: Directive not permitted here error

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile

I'm trying to run an nginx+gunicorn+flask app.
The following is the code contained in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf`:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto; 
# auto When one is in doubt, setting it to the number of available
# CPU cores would be a good start (the value “auto” will try to autodetect it).
 
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

https {
    upstream app_name {
        server web_1:5000;
        server web_2:5000;
    }

    server {

        listen 80;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://app_name;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto    $scheme;
        }
        
    }
}
```

I'm completely new to this, and the code above was based on some copy pasting from different sources...

If run `/usr/sbin/nginx`, I get the error `nginx: [emerg] "user" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:1`.

I've read some answer, but couldn't figure out how to adapt them to my case.

Note: I'm using this in a docker container, from an Ubuntu image. Also, I've been reading the documentation on Nginx, but I have some trouble understanding it. Is there an introduction to Nginx for those new to this?

Comment: Is your nginx inside the docker container ?

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the Nginx configuration across all included files. This is probably an included file. The Nginx configuration file is probably located at `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

Comment: @user655941 yes.

Comment: @RichardSmith Yes... I've also included the code from nginx.conf  file in the question/post.

Comment: We need to see the contents of both `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and `/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf`. The first is your Nginx configuration file, and the second is the included file that's generating the error. Its not clear which one you posted in your question as they both have the same name but a different directory path.

Comment: @RichardSmith Many thanks! I've now understood my problem. I was setting variables which had already been set previously. ;)